# How can i set my background color through HTML5 getItem?

Tags: jquery, css, html, local-storage

Im using this code:

```
$(this).css('backgroundcolor', localStorage.getItem('bgColorr') + " !important;");
```

When i write:

```
alert( localStorage.getItem('bgColorr') + " !important;");
```

It gives me the proper alert, rgb(243,102,42) !important; ....

Really getting to me.. thanks guys!

edit:

Surrounding code:

```
$(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', localStorage.getItem('bgColorr'));
});

var colorOptions = '#000, #fff, #abf7ae, #f6cbe9, #53c68f, #53c1c6, #538dc6, #c6536b'.split(', '),
    colorDivs = [],
    colorsContainer = $('#colorsContainer');

for ( var i = 0, len = colorOptions.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var div = $('<div />').css('background', colorOptions[i])[0];
    colorDivs.push(div);
}

colorsContainer.append(colorDivs);

$('#header').hover(function() {
    colorsContainer
    .fadeIn(200)
    .children('div')
        .click(function() {
            $('body').css('background', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
            localStorage.setItem('bgColorr', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
        });
}, function() {
    colorsContainer.fadeOut(200);
});
```

There you go, thanks guys

Comment: Are you sure that $(this) is the correct element? Meaning, if you do something like $(this).text('TESTING'), does the correct element update?

Comment: @NSD, i think that the localStorage property is a part of HTML5 if im not misstaken..

@Joel, you might be right because im trying to refer to the body background with $(this)..

Comment: Is this inside an event handler? What is the value of `this`?

Comment: Could you also post the surrounding code. ie. what's before $(this).css(...

Comment: there, updated with the surrounding code (which isn't mine)

Comment: In the first line ($(function() { $(this).css('background-color...) – $(this) is something irrelevant, change it to $('body').css...

Comment: @Joel And there you go, thank you very very very much!

Comment: You're welcome! For future reference, jQuery's $(this) refers to an actual element (body, div, etc) only when in an event handler - like it is later on in your posted code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `'background-color'` instead of `'backgroundcolor'`.
- Remove the `!important`. You can't set this property from Javascript.
- You shouldn't put the semicolon at the end of the value.

---

Update:

In addition to the above, it seems that `this` is not an HTML element. You need to use a proper selector here, e.g. `$('#someid')` to select the element with `id='someid'`. If you want to change the body background, use `$('body')`.

To summarize, you should be left with:

```
$('body').css('background-color', localStorage.getItem('bgColorr'));
```

Comment: I allready tried that, and i did it again now just incase i did it wrong last time.. nothing happened..

Comment: It's still not working.. maybe I shouldn't use $(this)? thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in getItem or anything, but the capitalization of your CSS property name. It's background**C**olor, not backgroundcolor.

Comment: backgroundColor and background-color are equally acceptable in jQuery.

Comment: guys, obviously both works since the alert is showing up correct, the css property isnt changing, i think thats the weak spot..

Comment: ...but your alert has nothing to do with the CSS property name

Comment: no but i've set the bgColorr through that property...wonder what's causing this

Comment: Well, I for one couldn't get the non-capitalized version to work when I tried it.